# Product Image is not showing in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, product-images

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4. I have imported products by admin but I have faced problem product that image is not showing on search result page but when we open that particular product then the image is showing. I have configured all possible things but the problem couldn't be solved. Could anyone please suggest me any solution regarding this.
[image: image not showing]

Comment: can you please check image path with inspect element?

Comment: showing image path is :  http://www.sneezeguard.com/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/6/a652_aluminium.jpg   and Not showing image path is http://www.sneezeguard.com/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/50x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg

Comment: so problem is your cache image not generated properly

Comment: make sure you media/* is 777

Comment: But other product images are showing only new added product's images are not showing.

Comment: Flush product cache and test please